# Storing JWT token ID in $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

I am working on my first angular application and using JWT to authenticate users.  Once the user is logged in sucessfully I am storing the token in a $rootScope object, i.e.

```
$rootScope.sessionStorage = {
    "token" : null,
    "loggedIn" : false,
    "userId" : null
};
```

I then use this when making API calls.

Is this a bad place to store variables that will be used across the application?  I understand that the value will be lost if the user refreshes or closes the window but this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not worried about refreshing getting rid of the token, then storing it in memory is fine.

However, *if* you're going to store it in memory, I think the more semantic and scalable place to store the token would be as a constant:

```
app.constant('TOKEN', token);
```

`$rootScope` implicitly makes things automatically available to all controllers without injection, which I don't think is what you necessarily need in this case.

You can just inject the constant where you need it (which would probably be in an interceptor):

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myRequestInterceptor');
```

Your implementation of the interceptor is up to you, but normally it'll just involve patching an `Authorization` header with a `Bearer <token>` field.

Using local storage is pretty simple. [`angular-storage`](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage) makes this pretty easy (it's an injectable service). The investment to instead store in local storage would be minimal compared to just storing it in memory as a constant.

Comment: @JonHunter, no problem, glad it's helpful.